# How big (how much memory) can a process get (allocate) in xv6?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

Suppose I want to use malloc() to allocated some memory in the process

```
    for(i = 0; i < SOME_NUM; ++i)
        int *x = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

What is the biggest number that I can set SOME_NUM to?

Comment: This looks like a question of how many allocations and not the size of memory allocated.

Comment: Yeah, but SOME_NUM * sizeof(int) will be the amount of memory allocated right? Sorry I am new to system programming, maybe I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xv6 the physical memory is limited and you can see the constant PHYSTOP which is `224MB` for simplicity reasons. Some of that memory is accommodating kernel code and other stuff, so the rest could be used by a process if needs to consume rest of physical memory.

Note: PHYSTOP could be changed, but then you will have to modify the mappages function to map all pages.

Note 2: pages are being allocated, so you could place `PHYSTOP`\ `pagesize` in loop. Well I'm cheating here because again, kernel data structures and code are already occupying a portion of physical memory.

Comment: Thank you Tony. But in Note 2: is that a back slash '\' or division sign '/'? If it's '/', why so? Because PHYSTOP is how much memory we can allocated for one process, and PHYSTOP/PGSIZE would be maximum number of pages allowed for one process. What if I'm not allocating int * but some other bigger stuff, whose size is, say, 16 bytes, can we still allocated PHYSTOP/PGSIZE many of that?

Comment: @K.Wu I meant division and allocating all pages = allocating PHYSTOP. It is the same. 
As far as I can remember in xv6 pages are allocated, I will reread that part of code later tonight.

Comment: Hi Tony, can I ask you another question? I don't understand what this means. In  "mmu.h" file, there are 2 lines of code, PGROUNDUP(sz)  (((sz)+PGSIZE-1) & ~(PGSIZE-1))   and   PGROUNDDOWN(a) (((a)) & ~(PGSIZE-1)), what do they do exactly?